# How can I stop monsters invading my mine/tunnels?

Tags: terraria

I have been playing Terraria for a few hours now, and have a reasonable sized mine underneath my house. It is well lit and I have never had any monsters spawn inside or even near me while in there - however when I am descending into my mine I often find zombies dropping down and landing on my head..

One thing that was suggested is that they are spawning in side tunnels off from my main shaft, but I don't have any!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Chances are they are spawning above you in the mine. Any kind of wall (stone or wood) except dirt will stop monsters spawning. I believe the walls are what stop monsters spawning unlike Minecraft's light level system.

If you've just dug straight into the earth, use the hammer to remove the dirt walls and replace with stone.

The other option is there is a blood moon on and the zombies broke through your house.

Comment: Yep it looks like they are spawning in my house as I have dirt walls, thanks

Comment: Dirt walls in the house? You won't get any NPCS :)

Comment: It's because I built my house into the side of a hill, half of my walls were dirt and I filled the rest in - I broke it up with a hammer and now I don't get anything spawn in there :D

Comment: This doesn't always seem to be the case in the underworld...

Answer (score -4):

**Answers**

- 1 dig all the walls
- 2 put a thin layer of water
- 3 Deal With it

Comment: While this might be answer, it's not a very good one.

Comment: While the first point is relevant the 2nd point doesn't make too much sense (as such could be elaborated on) and the 3rd point is irrelevant and non constructive